# Setting up Model Changes for DB Migrations MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've created a standard MVC app in visual studio 2015, with the few basics automatic steps "New Project --> ASP.NET Web Application --> Individual User Account".  I've created a table Menus directly in the DB. The question is: how to update the model directory to ad the relatice class from the database? there are a lot of tutorials about migrate the db from the models but I can't find the opposite. Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menus](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](250) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: This will help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework you can choose between three different approaches: Code first, Database first, and Model first. Check the link for more info: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/choosing-development-approach-with-entity-framework.aspx

Since you are manually creating the database tables, it looks like you want to use the Database first approach.

In order to create a data model in Visual Studio based on your existing database, you need to:

1. Add a "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" to your project.
2. In the first step of the wizard, select "EF Designer from database".
3. Specify the connection details (Server, database and authentication)
4. Select what entities should be in your model (you can include tables, views, stored procedures and functions).

After all those steps, an edmx file will be created with your model in it. Once you save this, all the classes will be generated.

If you want to modify an existing model, you can right click on your edmx file, select update model from database and follow the steps specified above.

Check this link for a more detailed explanation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878